# View is missing while using hardware acceleration in Android

Tags: android, rendering, android-custom-view, hardware-acceleration

I have an activity with one [HorizontalGridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView.html), where each cell shows one [BaseCardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/BaseCardView.html). User can switch away from my activity and perform an action which adds one more card to the list. Now when user comes back to the activity, at times the newly added card is not visible! Checking the view hierarchy from the code shows all elements are properly created and are in place, but when I do a "Dump View Hierarchy", there is no view drawn at that spot!

I figured out the problem is with hardware acceleration. As mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html):

> Problems usually manifest themselves as invisible elements,
>   exceptions, or wrongly rendered pixels.

So if I turn off hardware acceleration in the whole application, the views are drawn properly, otherwise not. I also tried to turn off HA only on View or at most Activity level, but the problem still occurs.

Now the problem is that I cannot turn off Hardware Acceleration, it massively affects the performance of the application. Turning HA off makes all animation to render poorly, and frame-drops become very obvious.

Any idea how I can force this view to redraw itself, and at the same time keep HA on?

thanks,

P.S: This application is for an OEM, so I am not worried about how it behaves on other devices/phones, as it's going to be installed on only once type of device, and it has to perform well on that one device only.

Comment: do you use fragments? I had really, really weird bugs when forgetting to use getChildFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager. Side note: this is exactly why I use Nexus and wouldn't recommend anyone buying other phone.

Comment: No this is just an activity. Also the device is a custom device for an OEM not a phone

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you other than suggest it is probably just an android bug